# Issue after upgrade to 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I made an upgrade from **v2.3.3** to **v2.3.4** and now when I try to edit a product I receive this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductLink/CollectionProvider.php on line 185
```

Any idea where this error might be?

BR

Answer (score 0):

in `exception.log`, I found this error

```
temando.CRITICAL: "accountId" is required. Enter and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\InputException(code: 0): \"accountId\" is required. Enter and try again. at /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php:91)"}
```

after I search on google I found this solution
https://magenaut.com/fix-error-after-disable-temando_shipping/

Comment: I deactivated the Temando Shipping module and deleted the files but the error persists in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

The Temando extension disabled can't fix the same problem for me. I found this variable `$this->mapProviders` is empty in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductLink/CollectionProvider.php file. This caused the problem. not sure what happened. I solved this problem by modifying the core magento file in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductLink/CollectionProvider.php. In `getMap` function, add this after `if (!$types) {...}`. So it'd be:

```
...
public function getMap(array $products, array $types): array
{
    if (!$types) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Types are required');
    }
   //FIX Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductLink/CollectionProvider.php on line 185
    if (!(is_array($this->mapProviders))) {
        $this->mapProviders = array(
            ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(LinkedMapProvider::class)
        );
    }
   ...
}
...
```

You need to import a few files as well on the top of this file:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\CollectionProvider\LinkedMapProvider;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
```

I know this fix is not clean as magento way. let me know if there is a better fix.